# Disable component if environment angular is production

Tags: angular, typescript

I have something like this

**enviroment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

And in **app.module.ts**

I have something like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, VersionComponent],
  imports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem I have is that based on environment.production i need to declare or not to declare **VersionComponent**

Something like this

```
if (environment.production) {VersionComponent}
```

The problem is that **if** is not allowed **declarations**, has someone had similar problem?

Answer (score 4):

Module metadata is consumed by the angular compiler, which only supports [subset of JavaScript](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#expression-syntax-limitations). Fortunately, that subset includes the conditional and spread operators, allowing us to write:

```
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ...(environment.production ? [VersionComponent] : []),
],
```

Or course, this may cause syntax errors if any templates make use of the undefined component ...

Alternatively, you could replace the component with a different definition that has the same selector, but doesn't do anything:

```
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  environment.production ? VersionComponent : VersionComponentStub,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const declarations =  [AppComponent];
let extraDeclarations = [];
if(environment.production) {
    extraDeclarations = [VersionComponent]
}

const finalDeclarations = declarations.concat(extraDeclarations);
@NgModule({
    declarations: finalDeclarations
```

Comment: Argument of type 'typeof VersionComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof AppComponent'.
  Types of construct signatures are incompatible.